# i need to return an entire html page using an ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, opencalais

i need to return the content of this page http://service.semanticproxy.com/processurl/ftfu27m3k66dvc3r43bzfneh/html/http://www.smallbiztechnology.com/archive/2013/12/why-creating-a-digital-storefront-is-crucial-for-your-small-business.html but when i call this function

```
function getResult() {
            var url="http://service.semanticproxy.com/processurl/ftfu27m3k66dvc3r43bzfneh/html/http://www.smallbiztechnology.com/archive/2013/12/why-creating-a-digital-storefront-is-crucial-for-your-small-business.html";
            $.ajax({
                cache: true,
                url: url,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
```

I got this in firebug:

segment.min.js (ligne 1)
GET http://service.semanticproxy.com/processurl/ftfu...orefront-is-crucial-for-your-small-business.html 200 OK 379msA.

Any idea how i can get the content of that page?

Comment: You're running into the same origin policy. Look into cross domain AJAX.

Comment: That URL does not allow requests from a different domain, you will need to host your own proxy script on your server that downloads and returns the content of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't work for you. the reason is that the html page you are trying to retrieve is not a valid JAVASCRIPT file (and you also can't use jsonp because it is not returning any json string.)

Your solution is to use a server script (such as php:

```
<?Php print file_get_contents(url); ?>
```

).

OR - if the website is yours , add a response to the script on request.